# Adverbs in the mid-position when there is more than one verb

Tags: verbs, adverbs, auxiliary-verbs, adverbials

I am doing a worksheet about adverbs. For adverbs of certainty like 'probably' and 'definitely', it says that they go in the mid-position and it gives this rule: *"mid: before main verb; if the main verb is to be, after this."*

But the example sentences are:

- "I’m probably going to try to make a seaweed flavour ice cream next."
- "She’s probably going to buy a new car."
- "I’m probably going to get a chocolate ice cream."

I thought that 'to be' in these examples would be an auxiliary? But at the same time, I thought that 'try', 'buy' and 'get' would be the main verbs, not 'going to'? So is the rule wrong? Or am I misidentifying the main verb?

Comment: Why would you classify "going to" as an auxiliary?

Comment: The main verb is the one that's conjugated.

Comment: Whatever source you got your "rules" from is rubbish. Take the first example, where the alternative *"I **probably am** going to try to make a seaweed flavour ice cream next"* is perfectly valid. It just carries a different nuance to the one you're citing. Don't waste your time with such poor quality teaching aids.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about the validity of some ridiculous arbitrary usage rule. Stacking up multiple verbs **[TO BE] + going + try + make** is pointless confusion.

Comment: I’d posit that the structure is auxiliary verb (inflection of *to be*) + main verb (*going*) + infinitive (*to try* / *buy* / etc.). So the placement is still in line with your “rule.” And having the adverb there does sound more natural to me, though I don’t think switching its location is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I disagree; the rules of adverb positioning are quite tricky and there's no reason to close this.

Comment: The rule says "if the main verb is **to be**," and all examples use that verb (contracted).

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. @alphabet I wasn't classifying 'going to' as an auxiliary, I was classifying 'am' as the auxiliary helping the 'going to' structure. I was trying to identify the main verb so I could place 'probably' according to the worksheet's rule. I can't see how 'am' is the main verb but I also can't see how 'going to' could be a main verb in itself - I thought the main verb had to be the action verb i.e. 'try', 'buy' and 'get'. But that doesn't fit the rule that the worksheet provided. So my question really was: am I wrong or is the rule in the worksheet wrong?!

Comment: *be going to* is an idiomatic modal construction.

Answer (score 6):

What is called "mid-position" in your grammar corresponds to what is termed "*medial position*" in *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*". In this latter grammar, this is defined as follows. (A more careful approach is shown in this definition.)

> (**CoGEL § 8.16**) **Medial**
> MEDIAL position (symbol *M*) can be preliminarily described as that between
> S and V:
>
> - The driver *suddenly* started the engine.  [1]
> - The soprano *really* delighted her audience. [2]
> - They *seriously* considered him for the post. [3]
>
> But when the V-element is realized by a verb phrase involving an operator,
> we see that this first approximation to a definition of *M* is inadequate. In the following variants of [1], [2], and [3], any native speaker would feel that the adverbials are still in the same position:
>
> - The driver has *suddenly* started the engine.  [1a]
> - The soprano had *really* delighted her audience. [2a]
> - They are *seriously* considering him for the post.  [3a]
>
> In consequence, we must refine the definition and say that *M* is the position immediately after the subject and (where there is one) the operator. This formulation will provide for interrogative sentences:
>
> - Did the driver *suddenly* start the engine? [1b] (*"Do" is the operator of negation. (user LPH*))
> - Had the soprano *really* delighted her audience? [2b] (*"Have" is the operator for question forms of verbs in the present perfect. (user LPH*))
> - Why are they *seriously* considering him for the post? [3b] (*"be" is its own operator (no do-support). (user LPH*))
>
> It will also provide for imperative sentences:
>
> - Don't *suddenly* start the engine!
> - Do *seriously* consider him for the post!
>
> In view of these examples, we see that an 'initial' adverbial in an imperative such as :
>
> - *Never* remove the cover.
> - *Carefully* remove the cover.
>
> must properly be regarded as 'medial'; cf 'We *never* remove the cover',
> *'*Never* we remove the cover'. One further complication can be seen in
> comparing the following examples with [2], [2a] and [2b]:
>
> - The soprano was really at her best tonight.
> - The soprano hasn't *really* been at her best for weeks.
> - Was the soprano *really* at her best tonight?
> - Has the soprano *really* been at her best recently?
>
> We recognize that *really* seems to be in the 'same' position in all cases. The description of *M* must therefore be further clarified to accommodate the fact that, in this grammar, we treat BE as an operator even when it is the sole realization of V. So also HAVE, in those dialects of English that would not introduce *got* in [5] and [7]; […]: Thus:
>
> - She has *really* a different approach to the subject. [4]
> - She has *really* (got) a different approach to the subject. [5]
> - She has *really* had a different approach to the subject.  [6]
> - Has she *really* (got) a different approach to the subject? [7]
>
> <sub>**Note**
> The claim that the position is the same (i) between operator and main verb as in [8], and (ii) between finite form of BE and complement as in [9] is strikingly confirmed by the fact that when the following was read aloud, it was perceived as [8] by some hearers, and as [9] by others:</sub>
>
> - The expression on her face was *seldom* discussed. [main verb] [8]
> - The expression on her face was *seldom* disgust. [complement] [9]

> "Before main verb; if the main verb is "to be", after it."

"if the main verb is "to be", after it" corresponds to the fact  that in CoGEL "to be" is treated as an operator when it is the sole realization of the verb.  "Try", "buy", and "get" are main verbs, but "going to" is not a main verb, nor any part of speech, this being so because "to be going to" is a verbal idiom. An operator is defined as follows in CoGEL.

> (**CoGEL § 2.48**) Not all simple statements have an operator, but when it occurs, it is normally the word which directly follows the subject. Provisionaly defined as the *first or only auxiliary*, it has a crucial role in the formation of questions.

In the construction "to be going to + < main verb >" the form "to be going to" is considered to be a semi-auxiliary, and "be" is considered to be the operator (do-support is not possible for negations and questions involving semi-auxiliaries). This is not a case of  a clean generalization of the first auxiliary principle as mentioned in CoGEL's definition because "going" is not an auxiliary as "to be going to" is a verbal idiom; instead it is a further definition of what an operator is: for semi-auxiliaries "to be" is the operator.

*A few semi-auxiliaries*

- be able to, be bound to, be likely to,, be supposed to,be about to, be due to, be meant to, …

Comment: Sick! I retracted my closevote!

Comment: This is why my linguistics professor said that English is as hard to learn as Chinese.

Comment: The CoGEL extract is really helpful, thank you!

Comment: Is CoGEL _really_ claiming that the word order in sentence [4] is the most idiomatic one? While possible, it sounds quite awkward to my ear, and [Google's n-gram viewer seems to confirm my gut feeling](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=really+has+a%252Chas+really+a%252C+has+a+really). It seems to have been more popular in the 1800s, though. (With "got" it sounds more natural, though, as [Google again agrees](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=really+has+got+a%252Chas+really+got+a%252Chas+got+really+a%252Chas+got+a+really).)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I agree with your main point, but that's how my grandmother would normally phrase the sentence, so I suspect the CoGEL examples are just a touch old-fashioned.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen No, this is not so; this example seems to corroborate the fact that, exceptionally, "have" is its own operator (traditional in BrE: "We haven't any money. Have you a lighter?"). Anyway, the examples are chosen as  likely occurrences so as to explain the determination of the medial position. For instance the use of the manner adverbial "fervently" could have been used in the rarer (but in writing, just as idiomatic) "he fervently prayed that …" (M); "he prayed fervently that …" (E, end position) is, however,  (1/2)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen  more frequent (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+fervently+prayed+that%2Che+prayed+fervently+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). (2/2)

Comment: In AmE one often hears things like "She really has a weird sense of humor".   "He really is a pain sometimes".

Comment: @TimR I mostly agree, but sometimes it depends on what you're emphasizing. "He really IS a PITA" vs "He is REALLY a PITA"

Comment: @Barmar Yes, but that confirming emphasis on **is** is not the only reason for the placement of the adverb **really**.  The emphasis could be on **pain** and **weird**.

Comment: Yes, Quirk et al give a decent explanation. I'd certainly not class 'be' as a main verb when it's acting as an auxiliary or as part of a periphrastic auxiliary ('be going to') / modal ('be able to / allowed to / supposed to' ...).